# Passing SharePoint User Info to SSRS Report

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

We are creating an extranet site for customers using SharePoint with SSRS integrated. We want to develop some reports for our clients. Somehow we need to determine the customerid from the person logging in (user attribute?) and pass that to SSRS so it can pass it to a stored procedure. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `User!UserID.Value` and set the default of a Query parameter to this value.

Comment: Can I retrieve other user attributes using that same process? For example, could I store their company ID in a user field and pass that to the stored procedure?

Comment: I doubt it. This is a built in field/Property off the built in User object in the SSRS Object model. I have not investigated it, but I don't think it's easy or at all possible to replace it with a custom object. However it may have property bag where you can store misc information.